# How can we show or hide components inside OverReact (library to build react components using dart ) according to conditions?

Tags: reactjs, dart, react-redux, dart-html

I am using the React package https://github.com/Workiva/over_react

I tried to show error for text field if a condition is satisfying. But even then on fulfilling the condition, the component(**ListGroupItem**) is not showing. ? I am calling **showError()** on a click function. props.inputEmailProps['error'] is set to true initially.

```
showError() {
  if (props.inputEmailProps['error']) {
     return (ListGroupItem()
       ..skin = ListGroupItemSkin.DANGER)(props.inputEmailProps['errorText']);
  }
}

  @override
   render() {
   return Dom.div()(
    (LoginInput()
      ..addTestId('loginEmailField')
      ..fieldId = props.email
      ..id = props.id
      ..inputProps = props.inputEmailProps
      )(),
    (showError)())}
```

Comment: What is "REACT DART"? How are `reactjs`, `react-redux`, `dart-pub`, `dart-html` related to this question?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I tried for tags related to React Dart , but couldnt find any . I thought it might be having some relation with react-redux and dart . My application uses Overreact , a library  for creating React components using Dart . PFB the documentation link :  https://github.com/Workiva/over_react

Comment: Thanks that makes it much more clear.

Comment: I'd suggest to create an issue in the over-react GitHub repo with a link to this SO question in case the over-react people are not monitoring SO.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer . I have posted it now.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to invoke the `showError` function.

```
@override
render() {
  return Dom.div()(
    (LoginInput()
      ..addTestId('loginEmailField')
      ..fieldId = props.email
      ..id = props.id
      ..inputProps = props.inputEmailProps
    )(),
    showError(),
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But still not working. If showError() is returning a component to display without a conditional if operator , it is showing on page load . But not working on calling showError() explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `props.inputEmailProps['error']` when the component first mounts? Similarly, I would recommend putting a print statement within `componentWillReceiveProps` to verify that `props.inputEmailProps['error']` is true when you expect it to be.

Comment: props.inputEmailProps['error'] is having value as true . Even then not displaying properly according to condition written on keyup event while entering text in textbox.